# Is there any specific words for referring to stores established in stair alcove/spandrel?

Tags: single-word-requests

There are some stores in some countries which are so little (about 1 square meter) and are usually established in the spandrel of the doorway of an apartment. Do we have any words for them in English?

Comment: in the Philippines we call it sari-sari store. also known as variety store.

Comment: How about a [nook](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/nook)?

Answer (score 1):

A **spandrel** is a space contained between a curve or arch and its surrounding frame, between points where the frame touches the arch. 
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spandrel

Assuming you mean a store which fits within the depth of an entrance in some way, I would suggest **Booth** or **Kiosk**.

Comment: Yeah, in the US *kiosk* would likely be used, though *boutique* is often applied to a small shop, even though the word doesn't necessarily imply that.  (One growing problem with *kiosk* is that it's increasingly being used to refer to a public computer terminal of some sort.)